# Calculate total derivative of multi-variate function at minimum value

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Suppose we have $$\min\limits_{u \epsilon U} F(y, u) = F(y, \dot{\mu}(y))$$

How can we derive the right hand side expansion in the formula below ? The first term on the RHS is obvious as it's a partial derivative with respect to y, but on the second term, it's not clear to me where $\triangledown \dot{\mu(y)}$ term comes from, seems coming from some chain rule w.r.t to u, but what is the exact formula/rule used to derive this ?

$$\triangledown\left\{\min\limits_{u \epsilon U} F(y, u) \right\} = \triangledown_y F(y, \dot{\mu}(y)) +\triangledown \dot{\mu(y)} \triangledown_u F(y, \dot{\mu}(y))$$

Comment: Use MathJax to improve to improve readability of your question.

Comment: Your first equation assumes that $F(y,u)$ attains that minimum for a $u$ that depends as a function on $y$. This is not implausible. They denote this $u$ by $\dot\mu(y)$. The rest is the chain rule.